# Set Google Sheets background color by alternating weeks

Tags: google-sheets

I maintain a Google Sheets based release calendar for my website, where we publish new content 5 days a week (sometimes 4, sometimes 6 or 7).

In order to make viewing the release calendar easier for my team I go through and manually stripe every other week a different color. Starting with Monday, ending on Sunday. I'd like to create a formula which will do this for me, so that I can save a bit of time. Given the dates below I've indicated what color I'd like a row to be. Could someone tell me if this is possible, and if so provide some pointers as to how to accomplish it?

```
Mon, January 4, 2021 <-- light grey
Tue, January 5, 2021 <-- light grey
Wed, January 6, 2021 <-- light grey
Thu, January 7, 2021 <-- light grey
Fri, January 8, 2021 <-- light grey

Mon, January 11, 2021 <-- default color
Tue, January 12, 2021 <-- default color
Wed, January 13, 2021 <-- default color
Thu, January 14, 2021 <-- default color
Thu, January 14, 2021 <-- default color
Fri, January 15, 2021 <-- default color

Mon, January 18, 2021 <-- light grey
Tue, January 19, 2021 <-- light grey
Tue, January 19, 2021 <-- light grey
Wed, January 20, 2021 <-- light grey
Thu, January 21, 2021 <-- light grey
Fri, January 22, 2021 <-- light grey
Sat, January 23, 2021 <-- light grey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in CF:

```
=ISEVEN(WEEKNUM(A1, 2))
```

[image]